Factory method for constructor with different params?
I am developing a software that requires to trigger alerts when certain conditions are met.

Developed an abstract Alert class with send(message:string) as the send alert method.

abstract class Alert {
    abstract send(message:string):Promise<void> {}
}


Developed DiscordAlert & TelegramAlert inherit from Alert.

class DiscordAlert extends Alert {
    constructor(private discordHookUrl:string){}
    async send(message:string) {
        console.log(`Sending Discord alert to ${this.discordHookUrl}`);
    }
}

class TelegramAlert extends Alert {
    constructor(private token:string){}
    async send(message:string) {
        console.log(`Sending Telegram alert to ${this.token}`);
    }
}

I noticed that DiscordAlert and TelegramAlert both have different constructor params.
Because discord uses a discordHookUrl and telegram uses a token.
Now the thing is that i want to create a factory for Alerts and dont know how to pass configs.
class AlertFactory {
    static createAlert(type, config?????) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'discord':
                return new DiscordAlert(config???);
            case 'telegram':
                return new TelegramAlert(config???);
            default:
                throw new Error(`Alert type ${type} not supported.`);
        }
    }
}

How can i accomplish that?

Should i pass the complete config for all the alerts ?
Is there a way to pass config in a generic way ?
Should i pass a config like Record<string,string> and do a runtime typechecking befor creating any of the alerts?
Should i use interfaces like IDiscordAlertConfig, and then the complete config will comply with the alert interface?


Is this what you are trying to do? https://tsplay.dev/mpoXaN Not that I changed constructor argument of one of them to take an object to show how different config types would work. If so I can write up an answer for you. Otherwise let me know if I am missing something.

Yea, kind of! Is this a good practice ?

@AlexWayne What about function signature overloading, that should force the configs when trying to pass ?

"Is this a good practice?" Sure? Hard to say. Best practices depend on context. A lot of factors go into that based on how this code is used, what's likely to change in the future, etc. "What about function signature overloading?" What about it? There's nothing about function overloads in your question. Which functions are being overloaded? When you tried this approach with function overloads did something go wrong?

This is usually best solved by making your function take a union of tuples.
For example:
function foo(...args: [type: 'a', value: string] | [type: 'b', value: number]) {
  //...
}
foo('a', 'a string') // fine
foo('b', 123) // fine

foo('a', 456) // error

This says that the function accepts two parameters. They can be 'a' and a string, or they can be 'b' and a number. But they cannot be 'a' and a number.
But we need to derive some different types to make your code work.

To better test things, let's make sure the two alter constructors take different types.
class DiscordAlert extends Alert {
    constructor(private discordHookUrl: string) { super() }
    async send(message: string) {}
}

class TelegramAlert extends Alert {
    constructor(private token: { jwt: string }) { super() }
    async send(message: string) {}
}

Now we need a type to map the strings like discord to a constructor for that name. That might look like this:
type AlertMapping = {
  discord: typeof DiscordAlert,
  telegram: typeof TelegramAlert,
}

Note that we want the typeof MyClassHere to get the type of the constructor of the classes, and not the type of instances of that class.
From that we can make the union of tuples with a mapped type:
type AlertArgs = {
    [K in keyof AlertMapping]: [
        type: K,
        config: ConstructorParameters<AlertMapping[K]>[0]
    ]
}[keyof AlertMapping]

This maps over all keys in AlertMapping, and create a tuple type for each of those keys where the first element is the key itself K, and the second is the type of first parameter of the constructor found in AlertMapping on that key.
Now you can use that type for your function function parameters:
class AlertFactory {
    static createAlert(...[type, config]: AlertArgs): unknown {
        switch (type) {
            case 'discord':
                return new DiscordAlert(config);
            case 'telegram':
                return new TelegramAlert(config);
            default:
                throw new Error(`Alert type ${type} not supported.`);
        }
    }
}

And now we can call this method and the first argument type will be strongly linked to the second argument config based on what that constructor needs.
// Fine
const discordAlert = AlertFactory.createAlert('discord', 'hookUrlHere')
const telegramAlert = AlertFactory.createAlert('telegram', { jwt: 'abc123' })


// Error as expected
const discordAlertBad = AlertFactory.createAlert('discord', { jwt: 'abc123' })


See playground
